# Students submit questions and the questions are ranked by popularity

Tags: voting, polls

I am preparing to move the courses I teach online. I would like to incorporate a platform that has the following features:

- The students can publicly ask questions.
- The students can upvote (and maybe downvote?) these questions.

This would allow me to prioritize popular questions so I can more efficiently communicate with students. Are there any platforms that have these capabilities?

I don't think google forms, surveymonkey, etc... have these features.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [collect ideas](https://pollunit.com/en/collect-ideas-and-feedback) feature of [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com). Your students can add ideas (or questions). Those questions can be upvoted. You have different sorting options including vote count. Optionally you can allow commenting per question.

[image: Example PollUnit Collection]

You can also create PollUnit [votings](https://pollunit.com/en/voting) where participants can also add options or questions. You can choose from different tools for prioritization like dot voting or star rating. I think the difference between a PollUnit voting and a PollUnit collection is best explained by the attached screenshots.

[image: Example Dot Voting]

PollUnit is free for teams up to 40 people.
Your students can also participate without registration.

Disclosure: I am one of the developers